# How to click on disabled button in facebook

Tags: java, facebook, button

I want to click on this disabled button but i can't
can some one help me

this is screen for button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yINpB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y5Vb.png)

Comment: why is this tagged with java and facebook? and where does that button appear? maybe you missed something to check before the button goes active? anyway, stackoverflow is for questions related to programming only, i am afraid.

Comment: this button appear when the account get checkpoint

Comment: You can't because it is disabled. Even if you by pass the disable check in the web browser the server will not let you do the thing anyway.

Comment: then how to enable it ?

Comment: it's disabled but not with the `disabled` attribute as long as the picture showing the dom is inherent to such a moment in time. Probably it has a style showing it as disabled but the culprit on why it doesn't handle the click event is probably because it has `pointer-events:none;` or the handler detached completely. In case the pointer-events is the reason, you could try changing that css attribute as `pointer-events: auto;`